# How to implement App Check in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I'm trying to implement App Check in my Flutter app for Android and have followed the flutterfire documentation. I have already complete the installation part outlined here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/overview
Now I am following this documentation for usage: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/usage

So I have added the `await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key');` to my Main method, right after the call to initialize firebase.

Now I need to enable debugging with the App Check and the documentation says I should add this dependency to my app/build.gradle file: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.0.0-beta01'` and add the following code snippet to my MainActivity.java onCreate method:

```
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

Which I have tried to do by creating the MainActivity.java with the following command in my project root folder: `flutter create -a java .`

So my MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
            FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
            firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
            DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
      }
}
```

When trying to run the app in debug mode I get the this error:  `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`

What am I missing? Have seen other posts with the same problem but no solution.

Comment: How did you manage to do this finally? I am in the same situation now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I postponed implementing it and never got around to doing it because I got stuck.

Answer (score -2):

This should be your `main.dart`

```
import 'package:firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
}
```

Note: `await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();` does not have `webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key'` for Android/iOS App

This should be your `MainActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.app // your package

import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.debug.DebugAppCheckProviderFactory

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/example"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            call, result ->
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/this)
            val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
            firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
                    DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what value for Channel should I use?

Comment: This can be any value you want.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense

Comment: That is just a string variable